# Search function that stops looking further after finding a result

Tags: c#, refactoring

I'm working on a simple search function. The user enters a keyword `request.Keyword` and expects the search function to "find out" **what** he's looking for and then search in that collection with the keyword. The three options for the **what** are `Name`, `Number` or `Code`

What I first came up with is the following

```
// Keyword filter
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Keyword))
{
    var searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(request.Keyword)).ToList();
    if (searchResults.Any()) _items = searchResults;

    searchResults= _items.Where(x => x.Number == request.Keyword).ToList();
    if (searchResults.Any()) _items = searchResults;

    searchResults= _items.Where(x => x.Code == request.Keyword).ToList();
    if (searchResults.Any()) _items = searchResults;
}
```

The problem here is that the program proceeds in the `if`-block after finding a search result and continues to search in the other collections. But since we already have a search result, that would be unnecessary.

The second problem is, that `_items` remains untouched when no search result was found. But in fact, the user expects it to be empty in that case.

In code, what I want to achieve, would look like this beauty:

```
// Keyword filter
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Keyword))
{
    var searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(request.Keyword)).ToList();
    if (searchResults.Any())
    {
        _items = searchResults;
    }
    else
    {
        searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Number == request.Keyword).ToList();
        if (searchResults.Any())
        {
            _items = searchResults;
        }
        else
        {
            searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Code == request.Keyword).ToList();
            if (searchResults.Any())
            {
                _items = searchResults;
            }
            else
            {
                // Keyword was set, but no result was found.
                _items.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the nesting is horrible (and this is simplified code). Adding new collections will make it even worse...

How can I achieve this with (more or less) clean code?

Comment: If request matches `Name` and also `Number` you want to return both or..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extract this method so that you are returning the result instead of continuing on, you can skip all the `else`s.

```
// Keyword filter
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Keyword)) 
{
    return emptyList;
}
var searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(request.Keyword)).ToList();
if (searchResults.Any())
{
    return searchResults;
}
searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Number == request.Keyword).ToList();
if (searchResults.Any())
{
    return searchResults;
}
searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Code == request.Keyword).ToList();
if (searchResults.Any())
{
    return searchResults;
}

return emptyList;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Way 1.**

```
// Keyword filter
var keyword = request.Keyword;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyword))
{    
    var searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(keyword)).ToList();
    if (searchResults.Length == 0)
        searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Number == keyword).ToList();
    if (searchResults.Length == 0)
        searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Code == keyword).ToList();      
    if (searchResults.Length == 0)
        _items.Clear();
    else
        _items = searchResults;
}
```

**Way 2.**

```
public static List<Item> Search(List<Item> items, Predicate<Item> predicate)
{
  var searchResults = items.Where(predicate).ToList();
  return searchResults.Any() ? searchResults : null;
}

// Keyword filter
var keyword = request.Keyword;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyword))
{    
    _items = 
      Search(_items, x => x.Name.Contains(keyword)) ??
      Search(_items, x => x.Number == keyword) ??
      Search(_items, x => x.Code == keyword) ??
      new List<Item>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your request matches in any of `Name` or `Number` or `Code`, and if you need all of them your code can be simplified as follows.

```
var searchResults = _items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(request.Keyword) ||
                                      x.Number == request.Keyword      ||
                                      x.Code == request.Keyword)
                          .ToList();

if(!searchResults.Any())
{
    _items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: That's a nice way. My posted code was a bit simplified. There is some other stuff going on, too. But I could extract and use them directly in the query.